# Two questions about Icelandic (syntax)

Tags: syntax, cases, tense

The following sentence is from Icelandic language:

```
Mér    vir›ast   tNP    [hestarnir vera seinir]
meDAT  seemPL            the-horsesNOM be slow
‘It seems to me that the horses are slow.' 

                                               From Holmberg and Hróarsdóttir (2000, pp. 1-2)
```

**Mér** is marked as dative, and **hestarnir** as nominative. It means that **hestanmir** is related to the tense involved in this sentence (i.e., tNP). My two questions are:

1. What are the tense elements involved in this sentence, and what's their relationship with respect to the nominative *the horses*?
2. Is the embedded clause participial?

Comment: _Vir>ast_ is not Icelandic; did you mean _virðast_? I’m not sure there is an embedded clause at all. _Hestarnir virðast mér vera seinir_ (with a more straightforward, but I think equally grammatical and likely, word order) more clearly shows that _hestarnir_ is the subject, _virðast_ is a modal verb, _vera_ is an excrescent copula, _seinir_ the subject complement.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I copied the sentence from reference above. May be there was a problem with typing on word or PDF. Anyways, 'the horses are slow', is a copulative phrase?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t think it needs to be; I think (though I’m not 100% sure) that _hestarnir virðast mér seinir_ (‘the horses seem slow to me’) is equally grammatical. Though I guess that rather makes _virðast_ not so much a modal verb, since modal verbs do require an infinitive (or in Icelandic sometimes participial) complement. (I’m guessing the PDF probably uses a non-Unicode font, mapping the glyph _ð_ to the code point >. It should be a ð, at any rate; single guillemets are not used as letters in Icelandic.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see the point now. Thank you !

Comment: Have you read the entire paper? cf. examples (11a-b), which are very clearly explained and analyzed in (28b-b'). https://doi.org/10.1016/j.lingua.2004.01.002

Comment: @AlexB. I was directed to this example from another reference (Richards, 2004) on Object Shift. There, it's argued that tense (T) values the nominative embedded DP (copulative subject above), it crosses *v* which is problematic for PIC (2000's version). I just wanted to understand the relationship between this T and the embedded nominative DP.